# Linear compact module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Can you tell me

> Why a finite module over a complete local ring is a linear compact module?

I am study about linear compact module, can you tell me some concerned paper? Thanks you very much!

Comment: sorry, my english is not good!

Comment: @tlquyen. There are some definitions about linear compact module that I have known. This is one: A module M is called **linear compact** if for each filtration $(x_i+U_i,i\in I)$ (here, $x_i\in M, U_i$ are closure submodule in M) we have

Comment: $$\bigcap_{i\in I} (x_i+U_i)\ne\emptyset $$. I am sure that has some relations between this definition to ordinary definition (every sequence has sub-sequencs converge) but I can not explain. Can you tell me more? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your settings. I thought that linear compact modules are just modules which are compact for a linear topology. In fact you are talking about 
 [linearly compact modules.](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Linearly-compact_module)  They are in general not compact.

In an usual topological compact space, the intersection of any centered family of closed subsets (*centered* means any finite intersection in the family is non-empty) is non-empty. For linearly compact modules, we only require this property for centered family of closed cosets $x_i+U_i$. So the condition is weaker.

Now let me show $M$ is linearly compact under the condition it is finitely generated over the complete local ring $R$ **and complete**. (So $R$ will be linearly compact). As I said before, the completeness of $M$ is automatic if $R$ is noetherian, but I am not sure this holds in general.

Let $C_i=\{ x_i + U_i \}_i$ be a centered family of closed cosets in $M$. Replacing the family with the family consisting in finite intersections of $C_i$'s (such an intersection is still a closed coset), we can suppose the family in "filtered": two members of the family always contain a third one. Let us first extract a Cauchy sequence of elemnts in the $C_i$'s. 
Fix a positive integer $r$. Consider the family of the classes of $C_i+\mathfrak m^r M$ in $M/\mathfrak m^r M$. As $M/\mathfrak m^r M$ is Artinian, this family has a minimal element $(C_{i_r}+\mathfrak m^r M)/\mathfrak m^r M$. Then 
$$C_{i}+ \mathfrak m^r M\supseteq C_{i_r}+\mathfrak m^r M, \quad \forall i$$
(they contain both some $C_j+\mathfrak m^r M$ which is then equal to $C_{i_r}+\mathfrak m^r M$). 
We construct inductively $y_r\in C_{i_r}$ such that $y_{r+1}\in y_r+\mathfrak m^r M$. This induces a Cauchy sequence in $M$. Let $y\in M$ be its limit. 
Let us show $y\in C_i$ for all $i$. We have $y-y_r\in \mathfrak m^r M$.

Fix $i$. Let $r\ge 1$. There exists $z_{i,r}\in C_i$ such that $y_r-z_{i,r}\in \mathfrak m^r M$. Then
$$ y=z_{i,r}+(y-y_r)+(y_r-z_{i,r})\in z_{i,r}+\mathfrak m^r M.$$
Therefore $y$ belongs to the closure of $C_i$. But $C_i$ is closed by hypothesis, so $y\in C_i$.

---

Former answer:

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a *noetherian* (not necessarily complete) local ring $R$. Let $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal of $R$. Then the completion of $M$ for the $ \mathfrak m$-adic topology is 
$$ \hat{M}=\lim_{\leftarrow} (M/\mathfrak m^n M)\simeq M\otimes_R \hat{R}$$ 
(the last isomorphism needs the noetherian hypothesis). In particular, if $R$ is already complete, and so is $M$.

If the residue field of $R$ is finite, then $R/\mathfrak m^n$ is a finite ring: 
we have an exact sequence 
$$ 0\to \mathfrak m^n/\mathfrak m^{n+1} \to R/\mathfrak m^{n+1}\to R/\mathfrak m^n\to 0$$ 
and $m^n/\mathfrak m^{n+1}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the finite field $R/\mathfrak m$. An induction on $n$ shows that $R/\mathfrak m^n$ is finite for all $n\ge 1$.

As $M/\mathfrak m^n M$ is finitely generated over $R/\mathfrak m^n$, it is also a finite set, hence compact. This implies that $M=\hat{M}$ is compact.

Note that you really need to suppose the residue field of $R$ is finite. Otherwise $R$ is not compact.

Comment: @tlquyen Thanks. It means $M$ is not compact if the residue field of $R$ is not finite. But in the paper which I read, the result need not the hypothesis finite residue field of R.

Comment: Can you tell me more. In the definition of linear compact module, why does the filtration $(x_i+U_i\mid i\in I)$ must require $U_i$ is **close** submodule in M. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to show $R$ be linearly compact in case it is a complete local ring. We have each $R/\mathfrak{m}^n$ is artin, so is linearly compact. Now, $R$ be linearly compact because of $R={\varprojlim}R/\mathfrak{m}^n$?

Comment: You wrote: As $M/\mathfrak{m}^r$ is Artinian, the family of the classes of $C_i+\mathfrak{m}^rM$ has a minimal element. But in general, $C_i+\mathfrak{m}^r$ is not a submodules of $M/\mathfrak{m}^r$, how can we apply the property of artinian of $M/\mathfrak{m}^r$? Or may be I understood something.

Comment: Sorry, I must write $M/\mathfrak{m}^nM$ and $C_i+\mathfrak{m}^nM$.

Comment: @tlquyen: the same condition holds for cosets.

Comment: @ QiL: The conclusion may be come from the exact sequence: $$ R^n\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$ Here, $R^n$ be linearly compact because $R$ is. What do you thing?

Comment: @tlquyen: from scratch, it is not obvious for me that $R^n$ is linearly compact, and the quotient of a linearly compact is compact. I don't know much about these objects.

Comment: @ QiL: I have learnt some thing from your guide. Again, thank you.